# Is $\rho(A^2) = \rho(A)^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that $\rho(A^2) = \rho(A)^2$? Is that even true?
I´ve tested it with matlab for random matrices, and the equation was always true.
I´m pretty sure that even $\rho(A^n) = \rho(A)^n$ holds, with $n \in N$.

But I still dont have a good proof. The easiest way to prove it is probably using the inequalities with matrixnorms, but it doesnt work out for me.

$\rho(A)$ is the spectral radius of A.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level

Comment: I think it should be true. You are essential comparing a list of finite numbers and its squares.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

use the defintion of spectral radius, and find out eigenvalues of $A^2$ in terms of $A$'s eigenvalues

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gelfand's Formula, that is; for any matrix norm $||\cdot||$ we have 
$$
\rho(A)=\lim_{k\to \infty} ||A^k||^{\frac{1}{k}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. Furthermore, all eigenvalues of $A^n$ are of the form $\mu^n$ where $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. One way of seeing this is  to look at the
Jordan form.

Hence $\rho(A^n)=\max_k |\lambda_k^n| = \max_k |\lambda_k|^n = (\max_k |\lambda_k|)^n  = \rho(A)^n$.